# How to tell whether a duration is over one hour across multiple shell scripts?

Tags: bash

I am trying to check running time and if it is more than an hour return an error, but the code returns false positives intermittently. In `firstRun.sh`, I read time as:

```
export START_H=`date +%H`
export START_M=`date +%m`
```

and in `secondRun.sh` I check the time as follows:

```
CURRENT_H=`date +%H`
CURRENT_M=`date +%M`
TIME=`expr $CURRENT_H - $START_H`

if [ $TIME -gt 0 ] && [ $START_M -lt $CURRENT_M ]; then
    echo "boot time is more than an hour"
fi
```

Can anyone help me find where the problem might be? Is there any difference between using `&&` and `-a` in if statement? Or any difference between using `[]` and `()`?

Comment: `&&` is a shell control operator. `-a` is an argument to the `test` command (`[`). You should store start time in seconds (`%s`) and compare that way.

Comment: does it make any difference to use '&&' in if statement rather than -a ?

Comment: @user3705440 Yes. `&&` terminates a command, `-a` is *part* of a command (ie. the `test` command and its synonyms).

Comment: secondRun.sh can not access variables set by firstRun.sh. Try to `source firstRun.sh`.

Comment: The `&&` is standard (defined by POSIX). But `-a` and having more than four arguments in `test` or `[` is non-standard; you cannot count on it to work in a POSIX complient (standard) shell.

Answer (score 8):

```
export BOOT_TIME=$(date +%s)
current=$(date +%s)
(( current - BOOT_TIME >3600 ))  && echo "More than an hour"
```

`%s` returns seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

#### Discussion: why seconds are better

Suppose, for example, that the start (boot) time is 23:00 and the current time is 00:23.  Then, `$TIME` is negative and this won't work:

```
if [ $TIME -gt 0 ] && [ $START_M -lt $CURRENT_M ]; then
    echo "boot time is more than an hour"
fi
```

Similarly, suppose that the start time is 12:03 and the current time is 14:00.  Then, the above won't work either, this time because of the minutes test.

Comment: Should include --utc from roaimas answer! Otherwise you can get screwed by leap-seconds and other stuff...

Comment: @Falco, I've been thinking about this and I'm pretty sure that `--utc` flag is irrelevant for `%s` (Seconds since the Epoch). It's just habit on my part to include it whenever I do date maths.

Comment: @Falco My tests confirm Roaima's comment.  On my GNU+Linux system, `date --utc +%s` and `date +%s` give the exact same answer even though my timezone is far different from UTC and is currently in daylight savings.

Answer (score 3):

Two concerns here

1. You have a potential race condition when setting the Hour and Minute of the current time in separate statements (consider the rollover of minutes at the top of the hour).
2. In your first script snippet you are using `%m` for minutes (but this is actually months). In your second you are using `%M`.

My recommendation is that you would be better with `HHMM=$(date +'%H %M')` and then splitting that into two parts. Even better, take the time as a combined value of seconds since the Epoch `SECONDS=$(date --utc +'%s')` and allow for 3600 seconds in the hour. (The `--utc` part avoids getting caught by local time changes twice a year.)

Comment: + 1 for noticing the race condition and the `%m` issue.